# Bluetooth connection with Android (versions: 12,13,14)using Java android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, hc-05

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I have encountered compatibility issues with my Android app in JAVA that uses the HC-05 Bluetooth module. We developed an android application to interact with the hardware machine. The app works properly on Android versions 11 and lower, establishing Bluetooth connections as intended. However, when used on Android versions higher than 11, it can be ono versions: 12/13/14, the app crashes and fails to establish Bluetooth connections; App stops working.

I have researched potential solutions and would like to seek your advice on addressing this issue. Here are the solutions I've considered so far:

Updating runtime permissions
Managing location services for Bluetooth
Adapting to API changes and new permissions
Bluetooth legacy mode compatibility
Manifest and Gradle configuration verification
Logs and debugging implementation
Testing across different devices and versions
Hardware and firmware assessment and updates

If anyone has proper solution on this...then please let us know.!

we tried all the possible things that will help to resolve this problem from changing the gradle version to SDK versions as well. but it's now working. Tried all the Github repos but it did not solved. Tried various AI models as well!

Comment: Does the app crash exactly at the point of creating a connection? If this is the case, can you please share your permission manifest file, your runtime permission code, plus the code for connecting to remote devices? In the meantime, have a look at this link which shows changes in Android 12: https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions

Comment: It would be great to share your crash log too